# Specify a user display name when opening a Google Drive document anonymously

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm doing some research for an application using Google Drive documents, but I'm running into problems with anonymous access and the user display names in the documents.

Ideally, I'd like to programatically create a Google Drive document and set the sharing permissions for that document to allow access to anyone with a link, without requiring them to log in with a Google Drive account.

Unfortunately, when a user clicks the link, they get assigned a display name like "Anonymous Coyote". Is there any way one can specify a display name in the URL?

To make things more clear, when Google's document would have an URL like "https://docs.google.com/a/famewebdevelopment.com/document/d/1LGXiFd5x0mHeo38ptqLm0U3jTWYE8qa0h0_w0eFsx8g/edit"
I'd like to be able to open that document by loading a URL like "https://docs.google.com/a/famewebdevelopment.com/document/d/1LGXiFd5x0mHeo38ptqLm0U3jTWYE8qa0h0_w0eFsx8g/edit?user_label=A_user_display_label".

Requiring a user to log in with a Google Account would mean he has to authenticate twice - once with a user ID/password for the application I'm working on and a second time with Google credentials.

If anyone could help me figure this one out it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The anonymity is not related to user's being logged in or not. You will never see a user with his/her name under these circumstances:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494888?hl=en

And there is no way to override this behavior.

Comment: Saw that as well, was hoping there was a way to fix this issue somehow.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en

The user is granted anonymity when he/she gains access through shared link or he/she isn't logged in.

The profile name is only revealed when he/she was invited directly.